# Jest tests for redux-observable

Tags: jestjs, redux-observable

I have the following epic, the variable SampleStores has some sample data.  How do I perform unit testing on this with jest?

```
export const incrementalSearchEpic = action$ => {
    return action$.ofType('SEARCH_STORES').mergeMap(action => {
        const incrementalSearchResults =
            // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
            SampleStores.filter(sampleStore =>
                (sampleStore.Name.toLowerCase().includes(action.SearchText.toLowerCase().trim())) ||
                // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
                (sampleStore.Location.toLowerCase().includes(action.SearchText.toLowerCase().trim()))
            ).map(sampleStore => ({                
                type: 'FILTERED_STORE',
                searchText: action.SearchText.toLowerCase().trim(),
                store: sampleStore
            }));

        //Create the interval to emit an item every second
        return Observable.interval(1000)
            .take(incrementalSearchResults.length).map(t => incrementalSearchResults[t]);
    });
};
```

Comment: I don't think it would be different in Jest vs any of the others, except Jest's API is slightly different but that's not unique to testing redux-observable code.